# Facebook Login Error Code 1 Sub code 1357045

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have implemented a login with facebook method in my website. Originally it works fine, but suddenly this past few days it won't work anymore, even tough I don't change any source code or settings. After some tracing, I found the problem is when I call `FB.api /me?` it returns this error:

```
Error Code 1
Error Sub Code 1357045
Message Unknown Error (empty response)
Type Http
Status 0
```

Does anyone can help me, please ??

FIXED:
Problem solve at this thread [Facebook Login JAvascript SDK, Content Securty Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539993/facebook-login-javascript-sdk-content-securty-policy)

Comment: For this kind of scenario i suggest you to try the graph api explorer first. If you still can't find the problem then submit a bug report to https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ .

Comment: I've tried using the graph explorer, it fetch the data just fine with no error. But in my web application still showing that error.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report, still waiting for response.

Comment: still no response to my bug report. Does anyone could help??

Comment: FIXED at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539993/facebook-login-javascript-sdk-content-securty-policy

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also this error can be because of some extension added to your browsers such as addBlock, Ghostery etc. In my case it was Ghostery.

Comment: This worked for me, cheers. Had to whitelist my website in Ghostery, and will now add a warning telling my users that they may need to do the same if they encounter the same problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can I find such extensions in my iphone safari app.Because I am facing this issue in iphone application.