# Facebook Login JAvascript SDK, Content Securty Policy

Tags: php, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, content-security-policy

I've implement login with facebook (with javascript SDK method) in my website, it works perfectly if I disable my CSP (content security policy) but wont work if I enable it, below is my CSP code, can anyone enlighten me, what did I Miss?

```
default-src 'none';
connect-src 'self';
frame-src https://www.facebook.com https://staticxx.facebook.com http://staticxx.facebook.com;
img-src 'self' https://*.facebook.com https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net;
script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com https://connect.facebook.net https://graph.facebook.com;
```

PS: I've been searching 'facebook login CSP' but no luck, please help.

Comment: What exact CSP error do you get in Console?

Comment: In my CSP report is clean there is no error, but the facebook api return me this error if I enable my CSP;
{"error":{"code":1,"error_subcode":1357045,"message":"unknown error (empty response)","type":"http","status":0}} that is what was returned when calling


FB.api('/me?fields=name,gender,email', function (response) {
alert(JSON.stringify(response));
});

Comment: Hi,Stephen R Thank you for your insight, I looked at the mozilla developer tools, tabs console there is CSP warning that graph.facebook.com was block in connect-src, so when I add the new policy, it works. Thank You very much!!

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information for Facebook sing-in headers out here but this is a list that works for me. I use only Facebook sing-in button and nothing else here:

```
script-src 'self' https://connect.facebook.net/;
connect-src 'self' https://www.facebook.com/;
```